# What word or phrase is best in "...would make you **give up** other fruits."

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

> An apple has enough nutritional benefits that would make you **"give
>   up"** other fruits.

If I wanted to use the exact same sentence above, what word or phrase is best to use in the bold part?

Context:

If I wanted to ask my doctor, for example, if eating an apple a day is good enough to do away with eating other fruits and vegetables, what would be the best way to word or phrase my question?

In other words, what word or phrase is best to describe that X is good enough that you would not need the others?

Comment: An apple would allow you to skip the other fruits.

Comment: This question is very broad, and the answer is a matter of opinion. There are scores of valid answers. _Abandon, relinquish, drop, quit eating_, ... ad inf.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Hrmm... I have difficulty using _apple_ as the subject of a verb like _allow_. Now, if the subject were the NP _Eating an apple_...

Comment: @P.E.Dant Fair enough, fair enough. There are a couple of semantic issues in the sentence (though not ones that raise serious alarms for me). I think the point that "skip" works here is valid, but in any case, you're right that any number of words could fill the gap. *Obviate the need for...*

Comment: @P.E.Dant Good heavens. Luckily within the editing window. Now let's have these two comments self-destruct...

Comment: @LukeSawczak If I were mod here, I'd leave them both (in their unedited form). Not only are they funny, but they demonstrate how to play with words. That's how kids learn English, and it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62365/discussion-between-luke-sawczak-and-p-e-dant).

Answer (score 0):

An apple is good enough that you could **abandon** other fruits.

You could also use "stop/quit eating other fruits", "solely eat apples", etc.